# Google Analytics Data Feed 400 Bad Request on First Request Only

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an inherited VB6 program that runs each morning to download Google Analytics feed data for several clients. The process does the following:

1. Checks that my current OAuth 2.0 `Access Token` (saved in my database from yesterday) has not expired, and if so obtains a new one. Naturally, when the program runs for the first time each day it gets a new `Access Token`.
2. For each client, post a request for feed data.
3. Processes the XML data received from the Google server.

My problem is with step 2 above. The first post using the new `Access Token` always fails with a 400 Bad Request error. Making a second post using the exact same data always succeeds and my program can move to step 3.

Here is an example of my POST (with Client Id and `Access Token` in `[ ]` brackets):

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?
ids=ga%3A[Client Id]&
start-date=2016-01-10&
end-date=2016-01-10&
metrics=ga%3Asessions%2Cga%3Atransactions%2Cga%3AtransactionRevenue&
dimensions=ga%3Amedium%2Cga%3Asource%2Cga%3Akeyword&
filters=ga%3Asource%3D%3Dshopping&
access_token=[Access Token]
```

This has been occurring for several weeks.

The error description (Err.Description) from my code is "400 Bad Request". The entire response from the Google server (less HTML) is "400. That's an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That's all we know."

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why the first request fails, but subsequent requests don't? I have even built in a five minute delay between getting the new `Access Token` and making the first data request, but still get the 400 Bad Request Error.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So you literally send the same exact request immediately after your first request and it works?  Have you tried something like Fiddler or Wireshark to verify the requests are the same?

Comment: A 400 usually includes a message to help troubleshoot the problem. How about sharing that piece of information?

Comment: ids=ga%3A[Client Id]& has me confused.   Client Id is used to gain authentication which you should have if you have an access token.   Ids is the Id of the profile / view in Google Analytics that you want to select data from.    Probably unrelated but if you are sending something like ids=ga:XXX-6v9cj8jbub068jgmss54m9gkuk4q2qu8.apps.googleusercontent.com  its defiantly going to cause an error.    I would check the actual request that's getting sent bad request means that theres something seriously wrong with the request you are sending.

Comment: I would also like to recommend that you switch to the V3 of the Google Analytics api.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for all of your recommendations. 

I have added the detailed error code to my original question above. 

The "ids" value in the request is the Analytics view (profile) ID, described in the docs as, "The unique table ID of the form ga:XXXX, where XXXX is the Analytics view (profile) ID for which the query will retrieve the data". Basically we have several profiles (one for each of our clients) that we need to analyze separately so we retrieve a separate report for each one.

Comment: I have also tried versions 2.4 and 3 of the Reporting API and get the same responses - an initial failure followed by success on the second request. I will try Fiddler next.

Comment: That error message you posted is not coming from Google servers. The 400 Bad Request is, but the actual message from the response is not being shown. The message is the helpful part. Whichever app/library you're using is where I'd start looking. For example, try making a bad request using the OAuth2 Playground and you'll see what an actual error message looks like. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Answer (score 0):

Using Fiddler (thank you M Schenkel) I was able to finally track the source of the problem.

My VB6 program is using the IP*WORKS! SSL component from nsoftware. The form had a single HTTPS component that was being used for (1) getting a new Access Token, and then (2) for getting the feed data.

Fiddler showed that the second use of the component was using some of the parameters from the first use of it.

I added a second HTTPS component to the form so my feed data request would start off with a blank slate and it worked.

Thank you very much for your help!